# Safe publication of java.util.concurrent collections

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety

Is volatile redundant in this code?

```
public class Test {
    private volatile Map<String, String> map = null;

    public void resetMap() { map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() { return map; }
}
```

In other words, does `map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();` provide any visibility guarantees?

As far as I can see, the only guarantee provided by [`ConcurrentMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentMap.html) is:

> Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into a ConcurrentMap as a key or value happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that object from the ConcurrentMap in another thread.

How about other thread safe collections in java.util.concurrent (CopyOnWriteArrayList, etc.)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`volatile` is not redundant as you are changing the reference to the map. i.e. ConcurrentMap only provides guarentees about the contents of the collection, not references to it.

An alternative would be

```
public class Test {
    private final Map<String, String> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    public void resetMap() { map.clear(); }

    public Map<String, String> getMap() { return map; }
}
```

> How about other thread safe collections in java.util.concurrent (CopyOnWriteArrayList, etc.)?

Only the behaviour of the collection is thread safe.  Reference to the collection are not thread safe, elements in the collection are not made thread safe by adding them to the collection.

Answer (score 6):

`volatile` is necessary here. It applies to the reference, not to what it references to. In other words it doesn't matter that an object is thread safe, other threads won't see the new value of `map` field (e.g. might see previously referenced concurrent map or `null`).

Moreover, even if your object was immutable (e.g. `String`) you would still need `volatile`, not to mention other thread-safe collections like `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

Comment: Not sure why, but I had in mind that because the constructor might use some sort of memory barriers, it would also provide some  visibility guarantees - except that the assignment is done outside the constructor!

Answer (score 4):

This is not just about the references. Generally, without the `volatile` modifier other threads may observe a new reference to an object, but observe the object in a partially constructed state. In general, it is not easy to know, even after consulting the documentation, which objects are safe for publication by a data race. An interesting note is that the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) does guarantee this for **thread-safe immutable objects**, so if the docs mention those two properties it should be enough.

`ConcurrentHashMap` is obviously not an immutable object, so that doesn't apply, and the docs don't mention anything about publication by a data race. By careful inspection of the source code we may conclude that it is indeed safe, however I wouldn't recommend relying on such findings without this property being clearly documented.

Comment: My idea was that the first time the map is used, it will resynchronize everything - which made me think that volatile did not provide additional guarantee. The partially constructed object argument is a strong one.

Comment: Although I am not sure if a concurrentHashMap can be partially constructed as it might use some form of synchronization in its constructor.

Comment: Maybe we should check the details, but they'll probably get very messy :)

Comment: [Checked it](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.java#640), this looks quite suspicious to me: `for (int i = 0; i < this.segments.length; ++i) this.segments[i] = new Segment<K,V>(cap, loadFactor);` This array population is not protected in any way.

Comment: Ha, but they fixed it in Java 7! Told you it's going to get messy... :)

Comment: it's ok as long as `segments` is `final`.

Comment: Marko, the segments array is protected by the final field fence, so you are guaranteed to only see the post construction value. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5 the BigDecimal conversation comes about as the fields of BD are not final.

Comment: the memory barrier is added at the end of the constructor, so it's ok to write to a final field then modify its content (before constructor exists). in the formal memory model, the important thing is not the write to the final field, but the freeze action `f` at the end of the constructor; it's fine as long as `hb(w,f)`, i.e. `w` occurs before the constructor exits.

Comment: P.S. Doug Lea won't make that kind of mistake even if he's drunk.

Answer (score 0):

**[Memory Consistency Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#MemoryVisibility)**

> A write to a volatile field happens-before every subsequent read of that same field. Writes and reads of volatile fields have similar memory consistency effects as entering and exiting monitors, but do not entail mutual exclusion locking.
>
> Actions in a thread prior to placing an object into any concurrent collection happen-before actions subsequent to the access or removal of that element from the collection in another thread.

Answer (score 0):

OK - I was able to construct an example that breaks (on my machine: JDK 1.7.06 / Win 7 64 bits) if the field is not volatile - the program never prints `Loop exited` if map is not volatile - it does print `Loop exited` if map is volatile. QED.

```
public class VolatileVisibility extends Thread {

    Map<String, String> stop = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        VolatileVisibility t = new VolatileVisibility();
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        t.stop = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(); //write of reference
        System.out.println("In main: " + t.stop); // read of reference
        System.out.println("Waiting for run to finish");
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.out.println("Still waiting");
        t.stop.put("a", "b"); //write to the map
        Thread.sleep(200);
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("In run: " + stop); // read of reference
        while (stop == null) {
        }
        System.out.println("Loop exited");
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, but here you just prove that the reference may never be observed. When publishing through a data race, that's the norm. It would be much harder to prove that you can actually observe a torn object.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Updated with a put to the map, which still does not synchronize anything. Yes showing a partially constructed map would be harder - not even sure how to do it / whether it is possible on my architecture.

Comment: Ah, that's what you had in mind. But as long as the reading thread doesn't observe the ref itself, no writes to the map will force anything. The easiest way to see this is to notice the allowed hoisting of `stop == null` out of the loop, compiling into `if (stop == null) while (true);`

Comment: So you'd need a more complex scenario where, despite tha datarace, this kind of optimization won't happen and then need to... well it gets **really** messy to reason about it. That's why we love and embrace `volatile` :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik It only happens if `run` gets compiled, so that's most likely what happens.

Comment: In the case of a `private` variable, I think the hoisting would be allowed even at the bytecode level.

Answer (score 0):

My impression is that Doug Lea's concurrent objects can be safely published by data race, so that they are "thread-safe" even if misused. Though he probably wouldn't advertise that publicly.

Comment: For me the main point would be that as long as it's not explicitly documented, the code that does it can be considered incorrect.